# How do I pull objects/array deep from a JSON parse in Android

Tags: java, android

JSON code: http://headytunes.co/?json=1

I am trying to pull the author name, but only repeating the first author in the JSON list. I am also trying to pull the thumbnail image and the multiple categories that come up from this JSON, but I can't correctly pull the image or the tags.

```
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Actors actor = new Actors();
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
                JSONObject jsonoTwo =jsono.getJSONArray("posts").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("author");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("title"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("excerpt"));
                    actor.setDate(object.getString("date"));
                    actor.setAuthor(jsonoTwo.getString("name"));
                    //.setTags(jsonoThree.getString("title"));
                    //actor.setImage(images.getString("url"));

                    songList.add(actor);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it dose not have any typo :

```
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("title"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("excerpt"));
                        actor.setDate(object.getString("date"));
                        actor.setAuthor(object.getString("name"));

                        JSONArray tags = object.getJSONArray("tag");
                        for (int j = 0; j < tags.length(); j++) {
                          // you can access each tag in this section 
                        }

                        JSONArray attachment = object.getJSONArray("attachment");
                        for (int k = 0; k < tags.length(); k++) {
                          // you can access inside attachment 
                        JSONObject insideAttachmentObj = attachment.getJSONObject(k);
                        insideAttachmentObj.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("thumbnail");
                        //or for accessing url :insideAttachmentObj.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("url");
                        }



                        songList.add(actor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting the first author name repeatedly because that is what you are doing in your code.

You currently have:

JSONObject jsonoTwo = jsono.getJSONArray("posts").**getJSONObject(0)**.getJSONObject("author");

.
.

actor.setAuthor(jsonoTwo.getString("name"));

The bolded part above is saying to grab the data of the first post then grab the author.

Update your code so that it looks like:

```
actor.setAuthor(object.getJSONObject("author").getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this whole process by looking at using Gson to create model classes from raw JSON.

To create a model class, simply have attributes of the same name as they are in the returned JSON, then parse your JSON into a list of models like such:

```
//Example model class
public Class Actor{
  String name;
}

....

//Where you are parsing JSON

public void parseJSON(String json){
  List<Actor> actors= Arrays.toList(new Gson().fromJson(json, Actor[].class));
  //Use the actor object
}
```